# Divergence in spherical coordinates starting from contraction

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

From "geometria differenziale" (Abate & Tovena):

$\begin{equation}
\text{div}(X)=C_{1}^{1}\nabla X=\partial_iX^i+\Gamma_{i,j}^iX^j
\end{equation}$

where Einstein's notation is being used in the local frame expression, and this makes sense to me, but when I try to use this equation in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with spherical coordinates, I get:

$\begin{equation}
\text{div}(X)=\partial_rX^r+\partial_\theta X^{\theta}+\partial_\phi X^\phi+\frac{1}{r}X^r+\cot\phi X^\phi+\frac{1}{r}X^r=\\\partial_rX^r+\partial_\theta X^{\theta}+\partial_\phi X^\phi+\frac{2}{r}X^r+\cot\phi X^\phi
\end{equation}$

This equation doesn't match what I've found on wikipedia or wolfram:

$\begin{equation}
\text{div}(X)=\partial_r X^r+\frac{2X^r}{r}+\frac{\partial_\theta X^\theta}{r\sin\phi}+\frac{\partial_\theta X^\theta}{r}+\frac{\cot\phi}{r}X^{\phi}
\end{equation}$

Is this for some normalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html), and I'm assuming whatever Wikipedia page you're talking about, use the convention common in vector calculus where vector fields are written in terms of the *orthonormal* basis $\hat r,\hat \theta, \hat \phi$ obtained from the coordinate basis by normalizing. Thus, for example, their $\frac{1}{r \sin \phi} \partial_\theta X^\theta$ is equal to your $\partial_\theta X^\theta$ because $\partial_\theta = r \sin \phi\; \hat \theta.$

Comment: But then why do I get the same value for the laplacian?

Comment: Because the formula for the Laplacian of a scalar (at least the one you must be talking about) doesn't involve taking components of vectors. If you view the Laplacian as the divergence of the gradient, then there will be differences in the formulae for both the divergence and gradient, which will cancel each other out.